# using ajax how can I display the data from a query in ckeditor

Tags: php, json, ajax, ckeditor

Hello this is my code but i can't see my query data in my ckeditor, can you help me

function mostrar(idnoticia){
$.post("../ajax/editor.php?op=mostrar",{idnoticia : idnoticia},
function(data,status)
{
data=JSON.parse(data);
mostrarform(true);
var Dto = data.editor;

```
        CKEDITOR.instances.myeditor.setData(Dto);
        $("#titulo").val(data.titulo);
        $("#descripcion").val(data.descripcion);
        $("#departamento").selectpicker('refresh');
        $("#fecha_hora").val(data.fecha_hora);
        
            $("#idnoticia").val(data.idnoticia);
    })
```

}

This is the form

```
 <textarea class="form-control" id="myeditor" name="myeditor"></textarea>
 </form>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'myeditor', {
        height: 300,
        filebrowserUploadUrl: " ajaxfile.php?type=file",
        filebrowserImageUploadUrl: "ajaxfile.php?type=image"
    } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
app.get('/profileface', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
// mongoose operations are asynchronous, so you need to wait 
PracticeModel.find({}, function(err, data) {
    // note that data is an array of objects, not a single object!
    res.render('profileface.ejs', {
        user : req.user,
        practices: data
    });
});
});
```